# Error when calculating mean + undefined columns selected + R

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a dataframe named **'directory'** which has 4 columns namely **a,b,c,d**. I need to find the mean of either column b or column c based on the input.

Both the columns b and c have **NAs and numeric values**.

```
TotalMean<- function(directory, pollutant = "b", id = 1:10)
{
    mean(subset(directory, ID=  id, select = directory[[pollutant]]), na.rm = TRUE)
}

TotalMean<- function(directory, pollutant = "b", id = 1:10)
{
    mean(subset(directory, ID=  id, select = directory$pollutant), na.rm = TRUE)
}

TotalMean<- function(directory, pollutant = "b", id = 1:10)
{
    mean(subset(directory, ID=  id, select = directory[,pollutant]), na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

I've tried all the above mentioned functions. However it gives me the following error.

Since I'm new to R programming I'm not sure why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention the error. The following is the error.
Error in `[.data.frame`(directory, , directory$b) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: Does `colMeans` is not appropriate for your question ? Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your dataset ?

Comment: I get the same error using colMeans as well

Comment: can you provide the code you're using for calculating `colMeans` ? (and the reproducible example ;) )

Comment: You are using `subset` wrongly. You simply cannot use it like that (i.e., programmatically passing variables to its `subset` and `select` parameters). Read the warning in `help("subset")`. And then use subsetting as detailed in `help("[")`.

Comment: Also, inform yourself about the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: I do not understand. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Also could you please let me know the alternative in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need subset, you can simply do the following

```r
TotalMean <- function(directory, pollutant = "b", id = 1:10) {
    mean(directory[id, pollutant], na.rm=TRUE)
}

directory <- data.frame("a" = c(1,NA,2), "b" = c(NaN,2,3))
print(TotalMean(directory,"a"))
print(TotalMean(directory,"b"))
```

Comment: Even with na.rm=TRUE? What data enters the mean function?

Comment: Yes. The data is numeric or NAs. Mostly floating point numbers.

Comment: @sreelekha I edited my answer to show that it works with NaN's and NA. The only reason I can think of why it returns NaN is if you calculate the mean of only NA's. Unless you provide a minimal working example showing what exactly doesn't work I can't help you further. Good luck!